# Webpack assetEmitted hook is not working when file being re-written(i.e. not getting emitted again)

Tags: javascript, webpack-5

I have following content in css file

```
h1 { 
  color: red;
}
```

I have following compilation hook,

```
const { writeFile } = require("fs-extra");


class ExtractAndWriteCustomStyleHash {
  apply(compiler) {compiler.hooks.assetEmitted.tap(
    "ExtractAndWriteCustomStyleHash",
    (file, { targetPath }) => {
        if(targetPath.includes("CustomStyle")) {
            const splitedPath = targetPath.split('.');
            const version = splitedPath[splitedPath.length - 2] || '';

            writeFile(`CustomStyle.json`,  JSON.stringify({ version }), 'utf8',function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error in writing custom style version", err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
  );
  }
}

module.exports = { ExtractAndWriteCustomStyleHash };
```

Above hook used in webpack file as follows

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // other configuration...
  plugins: [
    new ExtractAndWriteCustomStyleHash(),
  ],
};
```

Above code works fine and help me to get updated version whenever there is a change in css file.

For example, I get version as "{version: v1}" in CustomStyle.json for above css i.e.

```
h1 { 
  color: red;
}
```

when I change color to green as follow, I get version "v2".

```
h1 { 
  color: green;
}
```

Problem is when I undo change of css file as follow,

```
h1 { 
  color: red;
}
```

CustomStyle.json is not getting written with "{version: v1}".

what could be the issue?

I have tried deleting the emitted asset before generation and emission of new asset so that it will be emitted again instead of update of same asset file and asset emit hook might get trigger but it didn't work.

I am looking for hook / solution which can give me updated version of file in case of content is reverted back to previous content for which asset was previously emitted.

I can not clean my output directory on every hot compilation trigger as it has other static resources.